# Is there any way to delete hundreds of empty contacts group

Tags: applescript, contacts

Because of some unknown problems, I have hundreds of empty contacts group,I want to delete them all.

I try it on Mac and iCloud,they can just delete one group a time.

I haven’t found any good apps to do it in App Store,if you know one,please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, and I'm afraid I don't have the actual script anymore, but when I had a similar problem I ended up using [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html).

I first found this solution (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4088851) then tailored it to my needs with this answer on Stack ([AppleScript to compare contacts in two groups and remove duplicate from one group](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61093/applescript-to-compare-contacts-in-two-groups-and-remove-duplicate-from-one-grou)).

If I remember correctly, however, I backed up the few contact groups I wanted to saved and manually re-entered them after, leaving the script to be quite simple and just delete everything.

Have a stab at that and if you get stuck, I suggest posting on https://stackoverflow.com for some specific script advice.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Leonard Challis, I finally solved this problem with AppleScript.

I found the script here. [Script to delete all groups in contacts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65808/script-to-delete-all-groups-in-contacts)

Just copy the code to "Script Editor" and run it.

> ```
> set counter to 0
> display dialog "Name of group to delete?" default answer ""
> set theGroupName to text returned of result
> tell application "Contacts"
>     repeat
>         try
>             set theGroup to group theGroupName
>             delete theGroup
>             set counter to counter + 1
>         on error
>             exit repeat
>         end try
>     end repeat
>     save
>     display dialog "Removed " & counter & " instances of the group" with icon caution buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
> end tell
> ```

It will run a very long time if you have a lot of groups, just wait, it's working.